# Matamo - How to Export More Than 100 Records at Once

Tags: filter, export, analytics, limit, matomo

How do you export more than 100 records in Matamo through the web interface? Whenever I export a page with more than 100 records, it truncates the results to 100 rows(plus 1 header row):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on this is not entirely clear:

- https://forum.piwik.org/t/export-more-than-100-datefields/1359
- https://piwik.org/faq/how-to/#faq_54

The process is relatively easy once you dig a little bit, there is a parameter in the download URL named "filter_limit" this parameter is added the URL of the download link after it is clicked.

In **Firefox** the easiest way to modify this parameters is to right click the link to your preferred file type and select "Copy Link Location"(**Chrome**: "Copy Link address", **IE**: "Copy Shortcut"), then modify the link so it equals "-1", this is equivalent to "No Limit". Your link should look something like this:

> https://xxxxxxxxx.innocraft.cloud/index.php?module=API&method=Live.getLastVisitsDetails&format=CSV&idSite=2&period=year&date=2017-06-04&expanded=1&translateColumnNames=1&language=en&token_auth=xxxxxxxxxxxx&filter_limit=-1